# (surface) Area of an ellipse by integrating

Tags: integration, trigonometry, area

Given is an ellipse with $x=a\cos(t),~~y=b\sin(t)$

I do this by using $S=|\int_c^d x(t)y'(t) dt|$, so calculating the area regarding the vertical axis. 
Since $t$ runs from $0$ to $2\pi$ I figured I only had to calculate it from $c=\pi/2$ to $d=3\pi/2$ and then this times $2$. But when I integrate over those I get zero...

My steps:
\begin{align*}
0.5S & = |\int_c^d a\cos(t)*b\cos(t) dt|\\
S & = 2|\int_c^d a\cos(t)*b\cos(t) dt|\\
S & = 2|\int_c^d ab\cos^2(t) dt|\\
S & = 2ab|\int_c^d 2\cos(t)*(-\sin(t)) dt|\\
S & = 4ab|\int_c^d -\cos(t)\sin(t) dt|
\end{align*}

On those bounds $\cos(t)$ is zero, so how will this work?!

I notice that to integrate $\cos^2(x)$, most use $\cos^2x = 1/2\cos(2x) + 1/2 $ and thus find $1/4 sin(2x) + 1/2 x$.

This works for those boundaries (except for a factor 2 somewhere ???), but how do I know NOT to use $\cos(x)\sin(x)$ ?!

Comment: I know what method will work, I just don't understand why my own method does NOT work.
(1) Why rewrite cos²t ?
(2) Why does using the half of the ellipse give me the answer $2ab \pi$ instead of $ab \pi$ ?

Comment: Answered, thank you all :D

Answer (score 0):

I think the integral must be a line integral, covering the ellipse! The area of the ellipse is $\int\limits_{0}^{2 \pi} x(t)y'(t)dt|=|\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}ab \cos^{2}t dt|=|ab| \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1+cos(2t)}{2}dt=|ab| \pi$

Comment: There's something wrong with your math commands.

Comment: Yes, | instead of \ messed up the whole line - fixed it

Comment: How did you get to your fourth line ?

Comment: $\int\limits_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} \frac{1+cos(2x)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{3\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2})=\frac{\pi}{2}$. And when you multiply by 2, It will get you the good answer!

Comment: I probably do something I'm not allowed to do, as I integrate $cos^2(t)$ by first looking at the square $2cos(t)$ and then at $cos(t)$ itself, so $-sin(t)$. I suspect this is the **wrong** use of the chain rule? This is the same method as for $cos(2t)$ so that can't be allowed...

Comment: Thanks, that is the mystery of the factor 2 gone. I still had that factor from my wrong use of the chain rule. Oops

Answer (score 0):

Instead use double integration. Let $D$ be the domain enclosed by ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{a^2}=1$. Then

$Area=\iint\limits_Ddxdy$

Make the transformation  $x=ua$ and $y=vb$, then

$Area=\iint\limits_Ddxdy=\iint_{D'}|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}|dudv=\iint_{D'}abdudv$

where $D'$ is the area enclosed by the circle $u^2+v^2=1$.

Now make the transformation $u=r\cos\theta$ and $y=rsin\theta$, then

$Area=ab\iint_{D'}dudv=ab\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\int\limits_0^1|\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(r,\theta)}|drd\theta=\pi ab$.

Comment: Thank you, this works too. But I'm wondering where my own line of thinking goes wrong. Why doesn't that method work?